# CSS Margin Top Issues

Tags: php, html, css

Not sure why I am having such a hard time with this. Trying to add a 10px top margin to a

that is inside of a div. But that does not add the gutter I want and just pushes the containing div down 10px.

Styles

```
#item{width:738px; height:168px; background-image:url(../images/item_bg.png);margin:0px auto;}
#description{width:314px; height:55px;}
#description p{font:12px arial; color:#666666;margin:10px 0 0 30px;}
```

HTML/PHP

```
echo "<div id='item'>
           <div id='description'><p>{$row['description']}</p></div> 
     </div>";
```

If I use padding it works fine but I want to know why margin-top isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `overflow:hidden` in the surrounding `div`.

The reason why padding is working and margin is not might be the following:

`Padding` will introduce a gutter between the content and its surrounding element, whereas `margin` will introduce the gutter between the surrounding element and the nearest "solid element".

This is a bit confusing because we usually infer that `margin` will introduce a gutter between the surrounding elements and it's parent, but that's not true unless the parent element is "solid". The trick is to turn the parent element into something "solid" using an `overflow: hidden`

Quick example:

```
<style>
  #parent{
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #DDD;
    /* Try adding here overflow:hidden */
  }
  #surrounding-element{
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: #AAA;
  }

</style>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="surrounding-element">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/hRH6k/ and the margin worked for 10px.

Try `margin:10px 0 0 30px !important`;

Answer (score 0):

its working correctly may be you have another mistake .your code worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this post](http://www.search-this.com/2007/05/07/wheres-my-margin-gone-or-why-111/) for an explanation on collapsing margins

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to push down the content inside the div by 10px you can not use margin property or margin-top, you need to use padding.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing Margin-collapsing which is part of the [CSS Box model specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). You probably just want to put some padding on the parent element, rather than a margin on the child.