# CSS Top-Margin Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Does anyone know why I don't get a top-margin in the first div based on the CSS below? This renders the same in Chrome, Safari and Firefox 4 running on Mac OSX Lion (rendered the same in Snow Leopard). I would expect the first item to display with a 5px margin all the way around the inner div (except for the bottom obviously) and not just on the right and left. Why would the margin not also be applied to the top? Even if I specify margin-top:5px in the CSS it still doesn't render as I would expect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
        .outer{
            background-color:red;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }

        .inner{
            background-color:white;
            margin:5px;
        }

        .shim{
            height:1px;
        }

        .outer2{
            background-color:red;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            padding:5px;
        }

        .inner2{
            background-color:white;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                Margin
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div class="shim"></div>
            <div class="inner">
                Margin+Shim
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer2">
            <div class="inner2">
                Padding
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a common problem called "collapsing margins." Basically, whenever vertical margins touch (even when one element is inside another element), the margins collapse.

In this case your margin property on the inner div is collapsing into the `margin-bottom: 20px;` property on your outer div. To fix this, add a little padding or a border around the containing element.

Just tried this using your code and it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/hWPyD/2/

More info on collapsing margins:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: You literally have to add 1px of padding to the outer container and it will magically start working. CSS is so arbitrary, I'm not even sure what they specified in their specification.

Answer (score 1):

Its because there is a default margin and padding on html tags. Use a reset [like this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) to remove all of the browser defaults. (I highly recommend doing this)

Comment: Ok, I found the answer here on Stack Overflow by following a "Related" link just seconds after posting my question. The question was answered in an almost identically titled post [CSS Margin Top Isuses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524275/css-margin-top-issues) which I somehow managed to overlook.

The answer was to add overflow:hidden into the "outer" class like so:

    .outer{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

Next time I'll search more thoroughly before posting. I'll give credit to the first answer from locrizak.

Comment: browser defaults have literally nothing to do with this problem.